# Seeing exceptions from methods registered to SimpleXMLRPCServer

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I'm writing an xmlrpc-based python 2.7 program, using SimpleXMLRPCServer. I import the class with all our logic and register it with:

```
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("0.0.0.0", 9001))
server.register_instancce(classWithAllTheLogic())
server.serve_forever()
```

When running this in console I can see the log messages from SimpleXMLRPCServer about what messages are being sent, but all of the debug information from methods within classWithAllTheLogic() seems to be surpressed. If a method throws an exception there, I don't see any error message in console, and the xmlrpc call bound to that method just silently fails. print statements within the classWithAllTheLogic methods also just don't show up. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce this.
Test script *test.py*

```
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
class classWithAllTheLogic:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hi")
        raise Exception("INIT Exception")

    def hello(self):
        print("hello")
        raise Exception("Hello Exception")

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("0.0.0.0", 9001))
server.register_instance(classWithAllTheLogic())
server.serve_forever()
```

Run:

```
E:\tmp>python test.py
Hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    server.register_instance(classWithAllTheLogic())
  File "test.py", line 6, in __init__
    raise Exception("INIT Exception")
Exception: INIT Exception

E:\tmp>
```

**?!**

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, running on Linux. It seems you ran this script on Windows. Maybe it's OS-dependent? The documentation doesn't mention this.